# Regex to find some pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string which contains some pattern of text, and I need to find that pattern.

For Example:

```
var texttochange = ' [variable field="##Menu.name##" /]<br>
                     [img value='##Menu.image##' width='200' height='200'
                     borderthickness='0' keepaspect='0' bordercolor='#'
                     alttext='' borderstyle='solid'][/img]<br>
                     [variable field="##Menu.description##" /]<br>
                     [variable field="##Menu.cost##" /]<br>';
```

And I wrote the below regex to find this pattern `##sometext.sometext##`

```
var regexp = /##\S+.\S+##/gi;
var matchesfound = regexp.exec(texttochange);
```

According to my requirement I need all the fields ie `["##Menu.name##"],["##Menu.image##"],["##Menu.description##"],["##Menu.cost##"]`But in the `var matchesfound`, I am only getting `["##Menu.name##"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = ' [variable field="##Menu.name##" /]<br>
            [img value="##Menu.image##" width="200" height="200" 
            borderthickness="0" keepaspect="0" bordercolor="#" 
            alttext="" borderstyle="solid"][/img]<br>
            [variable field="##Menu.description##" /]<br>
            [variable field="##Menu.cost##" /]<br>';

var regex = /##\S+.\S+##/gi, result, indices = [];

while ( (result = regex.exec(str)) ) {
  indices.push(result.toString());
}
console.log(indices);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UaCLn/1/)**

Comment: +1 It worked, but you are pushing result.index in the indices, whereas i need the value... Anyways.. Thankz

Comment: @FurquanKhan: use `result/result.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

```
var texttochange = '[variable field="##Menu.name##" /]<br>[img value="##Menu.image##" width="200" height="200" borderthickness="0" keepaspect="0" bordercolor="#" alttext="" borderstyle="solid"][/img]<br>[variable field="##Menu.description##" /]<br>[variable field="##Menu.cost##" /]<br>'

var regexp = /##\S+.\S+##/gi;


texttochange.match(regexp)
["##Menu.name##", "##Menu.image##", "##Menu.description##", "##Menu.cost##"]
```